# How do I add a column to a df to sum all matched values of the entry in column A?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a series of days, users active each day and events for that user on that day. I want to add a column that gives me the total number of events for each user over the total time span in another column.

I can make it work with this code but I'm certain there's a more elegant way to do it. Please let me know what could be better!

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'users': ['Sara', 'James', 'Sara', 'James'],
                    'events': [3, 2, 5, 1]
                   })
df2 = df1.groupby('users').sum()
df2.rename(columns= {'events' : 'total'}, inplace=True)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='users')
```

This gives me the output I want with 8 in every Sara row and 3 in every James row.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed, do you know about the `transform` method? it returns a groupby in the same format as your current dataframe

```
df1['total'] = df1.groupby('users').transform('sum')
print(df1)
      users  events  total
0   Sara       3      8
1  James       2      3
2   Sara       5      8
3  James       1      3
```

just as a test

```
df1 == df3
    users   events  total
0   True    True    True
1   True    True    True
2   True    True    True
3   True    True    True
```

more here :

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html

https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html